# Android create new instance of the application

Tags: android, image, email, android-intent, flags

Is there a possible way to create a new instance of the whole app?

What i'm doing is this,
I'm taking a photo, sending it to the server, and then send a mail. (without internet or 3g).
The 2nd time i'm trying to take the picture and send it to the server to send a mail and turn on my internet i'm getting two mails.

One with the last picture made and one with an empty picture (0 bytes).

Now there are two option:

- create a mail sending queue.
- or if possible create a whole new instance of the application so the old data won't be overwritten.

I hope the last one is available with some kind of intent-flag or something?
So is it? or isn't it? because then i'll need to build a queue for sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possible way to create a new instance of the whole app?

No, sorry.

> because then i'll need to build a queue for sending.

That would be recommended.